# TextBox state changed after jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

In my program, I change the state of same TextBoxes in this way

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#textBoxId1").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#textBoxId2").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

and debugging with Chrome this appears to work;

Always debugging with Chrome, it steps into the following calls (reading from CALL STACK) of the jquery-1.8.2.js file :

```
jQuery.event.dispatch
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

After this the text boxes are enabled.

Is there a way to avoid the jQuery calls or other way to resolve this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a spelling mistake !

jQuery's `load` function loads data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

I believe you wanted to do :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textBoxId1').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#textBoxId2').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/EBzRz/

Comment: It gives me the same error !! The textBoxes are disabled during the debugging, but afetr the jQuery calls they return enabled :(

Comment: I don't get that problem. Is it related to a specific version of Chrome (I'm using Chromium 32) ? Did you try with my jsFiddle ? Can you produce a jsFiddle by your own where you can reproduce the issue ?